# Android DecimalFormat crashes the app

Tags: java, android, calculator, decimalformat

I'm having an issue with DecimalFormat in Android Studio.
I'm following this tutorial to make a calculator app:
[Tutorial](http://innovativenetsolutions.com/2013/01/calculator-app/)

I modified the code a bit and changed if statements to switch statements.
The rest is the same. When I try to run the app it crashes immediately.
I tried looking for a bug in the code and found out that this app crashes as long as this line is present:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("@###########");
```

After removing this line (and all code containing this variable), the app starts but it doesn't really do much (it displays the numbers but I can't do any operations).

My question is: what is wrong with that line? Should I change it in any way?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I dont see '@' in the documentation. What do you expect to be the result

Comment: I expect the app to run. Now whenever I try to run the app it crashes. I tried changing `("@###########")` to `("#########.##")` but still nothing.

Comment: if you deinstall the app, clean project and reinstall after you changed to `("#########.##")`, does it also crash? Please add the stacktrace of your crash report..